# Vim: Match character with a word on the left?

Tags: vim

I want to match the following `...` in Vim:

> Um...yeah.
>
> No...

I know in most programming languages you can do this:

`/\b\.\.\./g`

How about Vim? How can I match the `...` in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following one:

```
/\v\w\zs[.]{3}
```

It matches three dots that follow any word character, you can use some kind of quantifiers after the `\w` to match a minimum number of letters, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @alexchenco: In this case it makes no difference but I'm used to it, because it's more similar to other flavours that I also use, like `python` or `perl`.

Comment: Ha, I see. Long ago someone here criticized me for using very magic. He said it just make regexes more complicated.